# Is there a more efficient way to use assert with arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, unit-testing, testing, assert

in one part of my program I need to use assert to test multiple arrays (5 sets total), and I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do that besides what I am doing right now, which is basically just creating a new array every time. FYI I do have assert.h at the beginning of the program.

```
void UnitTest3D(void){
    double test1[3] = {0,0,0};
    double test2[3] = {5,0,0};
    assert(find3Ddistance(test1,test2) - 5) < 0.001);

    double test3[3] = {-2, -3, 3.4};
    double test4[3] = {-2, -3, -1.6};
    assert(find3Ddistance(test3,test4) - 5) < 0.001);

    double test5[3] = {-2, -3.2, -5};
    double test6[3] = {3, 1.8, 0};
    assert(find3Ddistance(test5,test6) - sqrt(75)) < 0.001);
    return;
    }
```

Comment: First of, you can't compare floating point numbers with `==`. You must specify an acceptable deviance.

Comment: Noted! I think I fixed it to something more acceptable.

Comment: If you are just writing a test module, then you should do it by hand, unless I'm mistaken and that's not what you're doing? When I am writing tests I will usually make a macro to create the variables and then perform the function I want to test.

Comment: If you insist on hardcoding them in code (don't!), you can always declare a structure like `struct test_case { double vector1[3]; double vector2[3]; double expected_distance; double tolerance; }` and organise your test cases in an array of `struct test_case` elements. You can then just use a simple for loop to run all the tests.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's probably more suitable for codereview.